# How to implement a 3-bit based hash function for hashtable lookup key?

Tags: javascript, hash, binary, bit-manipulation

I would like to have 8 possible characters in a URL, let's call them 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. Then I would like to use these as a key for a hash table lookup. Rather than doing the [typical](https://gist.github.com/vaiorabbit/5657561) 8-bit based hash algorithm, I was wondering how to implement a balanced/highly random hashing algorithm that is 3-bit based (8 characters can be encoded in 3 bits). So something (in JS for demonstration purposes) which would produce a well-balanced hash table given inputs that are multiples of 3-bits long. So you might have:

```
8
88
888
18
81
8181
```

As possible keys to the hash. The characters are from an 8-character set. So what I would do is start with this:

```
function hashBinary(bin) {
  // iterate through 3 bits at a time
  // build a nice random hash
}

function hashString(str) {
  let binary8Bit = str.split('').map(x => parseInt(x))
  // do something? to convert the 8-bit-chunk list to a 3-bit chunk list.
  let binary3Bit = new ArrayBuffer()
  // ... something
  return hashBinary(binary3Bit)
}

hashString('8181')
hashString('88')
```

How would you even begin to do this properly?

Trying to learn how to implement a good hashing algorithm from scratch, and also how to do it on non-8-bit strings.

Comment: There is no reason the "the typical 8-bit based hash algorithm" should produce an unsatisfactory distribution if that algorithm is well designed, like siphash. This would be true even if each character had only two possibilities (1-bit). Did you intend `return hash(binary3Bit)` to be `return hashBinary(binary3Bit)`?

Comment: "*Trying to learn how to implement a good hashing algorithm*" - before we start, please define what you mean by "good". Fast? Cryptographically secure? Some [other property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Properties)?

Comment: If the chosen hash algorithm is any good, it will perform equally well when passing only 3 bits of data instead of 8 in each step.

Comment: @Bergi this is for used for an in-memory hash table like implementing the javascript object functionality. It doesn't need any security, it needs to be fast and I am guessing uniformly distributed? Whatever you think is best for implementing a simple hash map that is fast performance-wise.

Comment: Do you mean with "hash" that it has a fixed (or maximum) size, and there could be collisions?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, any good general-purpose hash function should work equally well with your type of input – that's what makes a hash function good. But if you really want, you can **map your subset of strings bijectively into the natural numbers**, then **hash the numbers**.

A pretty easy conversion is parsing your strings as an octal number, only that the octal digits are characters different from `01234567` (here `12345678`).

```
function urlToInt(url) {
  // adapt `urlDigitToOct` if you use something different than `12345678`
  function urlDigitToOct = urlDigit => urlDigit - 1;
  const oct = url.replace(/./g, urlDigitToOct);
  return parseInt(oct, 8);
}
```

However, this considers some of your url strings to be equal. Leading `1`s are interpreted as leading zeroes and can be prepended or cut from the beginning without changing the meaning. For example `1` = `11` = `111` and `41` = `141` = `1141` (but not `4`!).

If different strings should always result in different numbers then three bits per url character are not sufficient anymore. You also need to store information about the length of the string. Here is a more general solution that *densely* enumerates *all* strings made from a given set of unique characters.
The enumeration works as follows: 0 is the empty string, 1 is the first character from your given set, 2 is the second character, and so on. After all characters were considered, we continue with strings of length 2, then strings of length 3 and so on.

```js
// use `digits = "12345678"` in your case
const digits = "abc";
const digitToVal = Array.from(digits).reduce((map, digit, idx) =>
  map.set(digit, idx), new Map());
const base = digitToVal.size;

function urlToInt(url) {
  // base^0 + base^1 + ... + base^(url.length-1) is a geometric series
  const countShorterUrls = (1 - base ** url.length) / (1 - base);
  return Array.from(url).reduce((acc, digit, idx) =>
acc * base + digitToVal.get(digit), 0) + countShorterUrls;
}

// manual test
["", "a", "b", "c", "aa", "cc", "aaa", "ccc", "aaaa"]
  .forEach(url => console.log(`url "${url}" has number ${urlToInt(url)}`));
```

Now that you are dealing with all natural numbers instead of a subset of all strings you can implement your hashing algorithm like you would normally do.